# CSS - Prevent table-cell from expanding container beyond max height

Tags: html, css

I am using a table based layout (using `display: table` properties). The container has a dynamic height (I have set min and max height properties on the container). All the inner elements within the container have their heights set to 100%. The idea being that they will always fill the available space.

The problem I am having is that elements that have `display: table-cell` will continue to expand above the 100% allocated space if they contain content that is taller than them. This happens even if I set `overflow: auto`.

I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue. Please see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/eSRA8/

In this example, the max-height of the container is 300px, but an inner element called `.tall-content` has a height of 400px. This makes the container grow taller than its max-height.

In Chrome this actually works how I want it to. However it does not work in Firefox or IE.

**Please note that since the container height is dynamic, I can't set a fixed height on any of the inner elements** (unless it is possible to use jQuery to assign the correct height on document load and on window resize, but this would need to respect the min and max height settings of the container).

Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve the desired result? I would like to keep as much of the existing structure as I can but if the same result can be achieved in a slightly different way then I'm open to that. Either way it needs to work the same in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

That looks to be a limitation of display:table;

You may be able to put the "container" in another div with max-height:300px;overflow:auto;

Here's some info which might explain why you are having difficulty:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout